# How to save tableView order after reordering cells in swift 4

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, swift4

I implemented the function canMoveRow to my ‘tableView‘. Now I want to save the new order to CoreData. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to have some sort of property (attribute) in your core data model so that you can save the order number into the database. That way, when you fetch, you can use a sort descriptor to sort on the order number.

Comment: How can I then save the new order to coredata when the user switches the place of the cell?

Comment: I think that's what I just told you. You look to see where each piece of data would need to be in order to generate the cells in the order they are now, and renumber all the data objects in that order and save.

Comment: Great, thank you. Do you have a code example for that?

Comment: I could probably write it if I needed to, but I'm not going to write _your_ code for _you_.

Comment: Ok thats not what I wanted to express but maybe I thougt you may have an example